# Code highlighting using markdown produces inline code blocks

Tags: markdown, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, github-pages

I am trying to highlight code blocks on [my website](https://www.anaghsharma.com/blog/creating-a-hyperlink-control-for-xamarin-mac/) generated by Jekyll. Currently, I am using the ``` markdown format to highlight code. But it doesn't work. Instead of highlighting the entire block, it highlights individual lines like this -
[image]

I also tried using the {% highlight %} tag but that produces the same result. It seems to somehow work and produce a block if I use {% highlight linenos %}.

The generated code is -

```
<pre><code class="language-C#">public override void AwakeFromNib()
{ 
 base.AwakeFromNib();
 AttributedStringValue = new NSAttributedString(StringValue, new NSStringAttributes()
 { 
     // You can change the color of link after uncommenting the following 
     // ForegroundColor = NSColor.Red,
     UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single.GetHashCode()
 }); 
    
 hoverarea = new NSTrackingArea(Bounds, NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways, this, null);
 AddTrackingArea(hoverarea);
 cursor = NSCursor.CurrentSystemCursor;
}
</code></pre>
```

I can't figure out why the entire block is not being highlighted.

Edit: Adding the code block that generates the above result -

````
6. {: .lh-copy }Now we need to style the text field so that it looks like a hyperlink. To do this we override the AwakeFromNib() method as below - 
```C#
public override void AwakeFromNib()
{ 
    base.AwakeFromNib();
    AttributedStringValue = new NSAttributedString(StringValue, new NSStringAttributes()
    { 
        // You can change the color of link after uncommenting the following 
        // ForegroundColor = NSColor.Red,
        UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single.GetHashCode()
    }); 
    
    hoverarea = new NSTrackingArea(Bounds, NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways, this, null);
    AddTrackingArea(hoverarea);
    cursor = NSCursor.CurrentSystemCursor;
}
```
````

Comment: Sounds like a point to raise on the Jekyll issue-tracking system.

Comment: Can you clarify your source? How _exactly_ are you using `\`\`\``?

Comment: @Chris I am using markdown. Kramdown as the markdown processor.

Comment: @AnaghSharma, thanks, but I was asking about the actual Markdown source you're trying to use. You're showing us a screenshot of the rendered result, not the source code.

Comment: @Chris My bad. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried ```csharp ?

Comment: @UmutD. Yes, I have. Didn't help.